# How to apply CSS to "views-exposed-form--view-name.tpl.php"

Tags: 7, views

I am theming a views exposed form which is a block. The views filters are displayed in a block and I am theming this using "views-exposed-form--view-name.tpl.php". I want to apply CSS to this template file.

How to do this.

Comment: you can write the styles in your main css file , why you are thinking to apply a css file to this template?

Comment: @Anoop Joseph: I want to apply CSS to only this exposed form template.

Comment: @Mohini How do you mean? That's what CSS selectors are there for.

Comment: You could probably add the CSS in <style>-tags on top of your template. Most browsers will probably understand what you want, it does result in ugly HTML though. 
You could also add the CSS in your main CSS file and use .view-id-viewname .div (etc.) to target elements specificaaly in that view

Comment: @Neograph734: Didn't thought of applying <style> tags . Using style tags and its working fine. Thanks

Comment: I've added it as an answer so you can mark the question 'solved'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the CSS in `<style>` tags on top of your template. Most browsers will probably understand what you want, it does result in ugly HTML though.

You could also add the CSS in your main CSS file and use .view-id-viewname .div (etc.) to target elements specificaaly in that view